# How can I fix deployment of node.js to azure app service that fails npm install?

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-web-app-service

I create a new app service with windows os, connect it to bitbucket and it checks out the code then fails on npm install. I feel like it should work and I cant understand how it is not working..

I put full error traces at the bottom.

First I got this error:

> Cannot find module 'sync-exec'

Well that seems like it is using the old node (my package.json has `"engines": { "node": "8.9.x" }` ) which I thought would be valid so I tried setting the environment variable `WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION` to `8.9.0` but it still errors this time with this:

> EPERM: operation not permitted, scandir

I read in some posts to try running `npm cache clean` it says it should auto-clean so from the console I try `npm cache clean --force` then I rebuild and still get the error. Out of desparation I try `del /s /q node_modules` then rebuild and now get a worse error.

> Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Maybe delete this folder was crazy. If I need I can delete the web app and start over though. I created a linux web app and the npm install worked fine but I have other issues with linux so it would be good to get the windows one working.

Here are the full log outputs:

```
Selected node.js version 8.9.0. Use package.json file to choose a different version.
Selected npm version 5.5.1
Updating iisnode.yml at D:\home\site\wwwroot\iisnode.yml
npm WARN lifecycle The node binary used for scripts is D:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\0.10.28\node.exe but npm is using D:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\8.9.0\node.exe itself. Use the `--scripts-prepend-node-path` option to include the path for the node binary npm was executed with.

> microtime@2.1.6 install D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\microtime
> prebuild-install || node-gyp rebuild

prebuild-install info begin Prebuild-install version 2.2.1
prebuild-install info looking for local prebuild @ prebuilds\microtime-v2.1.6-node-v11-win32-ia32.tar.gz
prebuild-install info looking for cached prebuild @ D:\local\AppData\npm-cache\_prebuilds\https-github.com-wadey-node-microtime-releases-download-v2.1.6-microtime-v2.1.6-node-v11-win32-ia32.tar.gz
prebuild-install http request GET https://github.com/wadey/node-microtime/releases/download/v2.1.6/microtime-v2.1.6-node-v11-win32-ia32.tar.gz
prebuild-install http 200 https://github.com/wadey/node-microtime/releases/download/v2.1.6/microtime-v2.1.6-node-v11-win32-ia32.tar.gz
prebuild-install info downloading to @ D:\local\AppData\npm-cache\_prebuilds\https-github.com-wadey-node-microtime-releases-download-v2.1.6-microtime-v2.1.6-node-v11-win32-ia32.tar.gz.5612-28c7359.tmp
prebuild-install info renaming to @ D:\local\AppData\npm-cache\_prebuilds\https-github.com-wadey-node-microtime-releases-download-v2.1.6-microtime-v2.1.6-node-v11-win32-ia32.tar.gz
prebuild-install info unpacking @ D:\local\AppData\npm-cache\_prebuilds\https-github.com-wadey-node-microtime-releases-download-v2.1.6-microtime-v2.1.6-node-v11-win32-ia32.tar.gz
prebuild-install info unpack resolved to D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\microtime\build\Release\microtime.node
prebuild-install info unpack required D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\microtime\build\Release\microtime.node successfully
prebuild-install info install Successfully installed prebuilt binary!

> node-sass@4.5.3 install D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\node-sass
> node scripts/install.js

Downloading binary from https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download/v4.5.3/win32-ia32-11_binding.node
Download complete
Binary saved to D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\node-sass\vendor\win32-ia32-11\binding.node
Caching binary to D:\local\AppData\npm-cache\node-sass\4.5.3\win32-ia32-11_binding.node

> uglifyjs-webpack-plugin@0.4.6 postinstall D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\uglifyjs-webpack-plugin
> node lib/post_install.js


module.js:340
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Cannot find module 'sync-exec'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\uglifyjs-webpack-plugin\lib\post_install.js:9:14)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
npm WARN Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, scandir 'D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\uglify-js\node_modules'
npm WARN  { Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, scandir 'D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\uglify-js\node_modules'
npm WARN   stack: 'Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, scandir \'D:\\home\\site\\wwwroot\\node_modules\\webpack\\node_modules\\uglify-js\\node_modules\'',
npm WARN   errno: -4048,
npm WARN   code: 'EPERM',
npm WARN   syscall: 'scandir',
npm WARN   path: 'D:\\home\\site\\wwwroot\\node_modules\\webpack\\node_modules\\uglify-js\\node_modules' }
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 8
npm ERR! uglifyjs-webpack-plugin@0.4.6 postinstall: `node lib/post_install.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 8
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the uglifyjs-webpack-plugin@0.4.6 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     D:\local\AppData\npm-cache\_logs\2017-11-22T04_03_47_200Z-debug.log
Failed exitCode=8, command="D:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\8.9.0\node.exe" "D:\Program Files (x86)\npm\5.5.1\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" install --production
```

After setting the version environment variable the error is:

```
Command: "D:\home\site\deployments\tools\deploy.cmd"
Handling node.js deployment.
KuduSync.NET from: 'D:\home\site\repository' to: 'D:\home\site\wwwroot'
Start script "built/project1/server.js" from package.json is not found.
Missing server.js/app.js files, web.config is not generated
Looking for app.js/server.js under site root.
Node.js versions available on the platform are: 0.6.20, 0.8.2, 0.8.19, 0.8.26, 0.8.27, 0.8.28, 0.10.5, 0.10.18, 0.10.21, 0.10.24, 0.10.26, 0.10.28, 0.10.29, 0.10.31, 0.10.32, 0.10.40, 0.12.0, 0.12.2, 0.12.3, 0.12.6, 4.0.0, 4.1.0, 4.1.2, 4.2.1, 4.2.2, 4.2.3, 4.2.4, 4.3.0, 4.3.2, 4.4.0, 4.4.1, 4.4.6, 4.4.7, 4.5.0, 4.6.0, 4.6.1, 4.8.4, 5.0.0, 5.1.1, 5.3.0, 5.4.0, 5.5.0, 5.6.0, 5.7.0, 5.7.1, 5.8.0, 5.9.1, 6.0.0, 6.1.0, 6.2.2, 6.3.0, 6.5.0, 6.6.0, 6.7.0, 6.9.0, 6.9.1, 6.9.2, 6.9.4, 6.9.5, 6.10.0, 6.10.3, 6.11.1, 6.11.2, 6.11.5, 7.0.0, 7.1.0, 7.2.0, 7.3.0, 7.4.0, 7.5.0, 7.6.0, 7.7.0, 7.7.4, 7.10.0, 7.10.1, 8.0.0, 8.1.4, 8.4.0, 8.5.0, 8.7.0, 8.8.0, 8.8.1, 8.9.0.
Selected node.js version 8.9.0. Use package.json file to choose a different version.
Selected npm version 5.5.1
Updating iisnode.yml at D:\home\site\wwwroot\iisnode.yml

> uglifyjs-webpack-plugin@0.4.6 postinstall D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\uglifyjs-webpack-plugin
> node lib/post_install.js

npm ERR! path D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules
npm ERR! code EPERM
npm ERR! errno -4048
npm ERR! syscall scandir
npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, scandir 'D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules'
npm ERR!  { Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, scandir 'D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules'
npm ERR!   stack: 'Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, scandir \'D:\\home\\site\\wwwroot\\node_modules\\fsevents\\node_modules\'',
npm ERR!   errno: -4048,
npm ERR!   code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'scandir',
npm ERR!   path: 'D:\\home\\site\\wwwroot\\node_modules\\fsevents\\node_modules' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     D:\local\AppData\npm-cache\_logs\2017-11-22T04_28_58_782Z-debug.log
Failed exitCode=-4048, command="D:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\8.9.0\node.exe" "D:\Program Files (x86)\npm\5.5.1\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" install --production
An error has occurred during web site deployment.
Missing server.js/app.js files, web.config is not generated\r\nnpm ERR! path D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\r\nnpm ERR! code EPERM\r\nnpm ERR! errno -4048\r\nnpm ERR! syscall scandir\r\nnpm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, scandir 'D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules'\r\nnpm ERR!  { Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, scandir 'D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules'\r\nnpm ERR!   stack: 'Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, scandir \'D:\\home\\site\\wwwroot\\node_modules\\fsevents\\node_modules\'',\r\nnpm ERR!   errno: -4048,\r\nnpm ERR!   code: 'EPERM',\r\nnpm ERR!   syscall: 'scandir',\r\nnpm ERR!   path: 'D:\\home\\site\\wwwroot\\node_modules\\fsevents\\node_modules' }\r\nnpm ERR! \r\nnpm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.\r\n\r\nnpm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:\r\nnpm ERR!     D:\local\AppData\npm-cache\_logs\2017-11-22T04_28_58_782Z-debug.log\r\nD:\Program Files (x86)\SiteExtensions\Kudu\67.61109.3117\bin\Scripts\starter.cmd "D:\home\site\deployments\tools\deploy.cmd"
```

After deleting node_modules the error is:

```
Command: "D:\home\site\deployments\tools\deploy.cmd"
Handling node.js deployment.
KuduSync.NET from: 'D:\home\site\repository' to: 'D:\home\site\wwwroot'
Start script "built/project1/server.js" from package.json is not found.
Missing server.js/app.js files, web.config is not generated
Looking for app.js/server.js under site root.
Node.js versions available on the platform are: 0.6.20, 0.8.2, 0.8.19, 0.8.26, 0.8.27, 0.8.28, 0.10.5, 0.10.18, 0.10.21, 0.10.24, 0.10.26, 0.10.28, 0.10.29, 0.10.31, 0.10.32, 0.10.40, 0.12.0, 0.12.2, 0.12.3, 0.12.6, 4.0.0, 4.1.0, 4.1.2, 4.2.1, 4.2.2, 4.2.3, 4.2.4, 4.3.0, 4.3.2, 4.4.0, 4.4.1, 4.4.6, 4.4.7, 4.5.0, 4.6.0, 4.6.1, 4.8.4, 5.0.0, 5.1.1, 5.3.0, 5.4.0, 5.5.0, 5.6.0, 5.7.0, 5.7.1, 5.8.0, 5.9.1, 6.0.0, 6.1.0, 6.2.2, 6.3.0, 6.5.0, 6.6.0, 6.7.0, 6.9.0, 6.9.1, 6.9.2, 6.9.4, 6.9.5, 6.10.0, 6.10.3, 6.11.1, 6.11.2, 6.11.5, 7.0.0, 7.1.0, 7.2.0, 7.3.0, 7.4.0, 7.5.0, 7.6.0, 7.7.0, 7.7.4, 7.10.0, 7.10.1, 8.0.0, 8.1.4, 8.4.0, 8.5.0, 8.7.0, 8.8.0, 8.8.1, 8.9.0.
Selected node.js version 8.9.0. Use package.json file to choose a different version.
Selected npm version 5.5.1
Updating iisnode.yml at D:\home\site\wwwroot\iisnode.yml
npm ERR! Cannot read property '0' of undefined
Failed exitCode=1, command="D:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\8.9.0\node.exe" "D:\Program Files (x86)\npm\5.5.1\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" install --production
```

Answer (score 1):

I found someone reported similar in npm https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/17671
so I set an environment variable of `NPM_CONFIG_OPTIONAL` to `true` and it builds without the permission errors.